# How to return a 2D array?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, return-type, function-declaration, variable-length-array

I was searching for an efficient way to create a 2D array and return it, usually I make an array of pointers, allocate memory for each pointer, and return an **ptr. I was looking for another way to do it because then I have to free every single memory allocated.

I was reading online that you can allocate a 2D array like this: `int (*arr)[n] = malloc( sizeof *arr * i );`
In which ptr is a pointer, pointing to the adress of `arr[n]`.

When I try to return arr, from the following function: `int *array_of_smallest(int count);` 
I get: `warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)[n]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

If I initialise another pointer and point it to array, then return it, I'm only returning a 1D array.

I think I'm mixing diferent concepts and confusing myself.

With an array of pointers I don't have a problem, but I wanted a simplier way to create a 2D array, also easier to free, but I'm not being able to return that array from my function.

Comment: There is another way! You can make a 1D array and use it as a 2D, by playing around with the way you index the data in the array, if this interests you I could write a more detailed answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a pointer of the variable modified type type int ( * )[n].

```
int (*arr)[n] = malloc( sizeof *arr * i );
```

That is the variable `n` used in the declarator is not an integer constant expression.

In this case the function should have the return type `void *`. And it can be declared like

```
void * array_of_smallest(int count)
{
    int (*arr)[n] = malloc( sizeof *arr * i );
    //...
    return arr;
}
```

In the caller you will write

```
int ( *arr )[n] = array_of_smallest( count );
```

In this declaration the value of `n` must be the same as used within the function.

If to use an integer constant expression like

```
int (*arr)[2] = malloc( sizeof *arr * 2 );
```

then the function declaration will look like

```
int ( * array_of_smallest(int count) )[2];
```

Or you can introduce a typedef name before the function declaration like

```
typedef int Array[2];
```

and in this case the function will look like

```
Array * array_of_smallest(int count);
```

Comment: What if I had used: int (*arr)[2] = malloc( sizeof *arr * i ); Being "2" an integer constant, then my return type would be: int *?

Comment: @JoaoLima, it would be `int(*)[2]`. Define your function as `int (*array_of_smallest(int count))[2] { .... }`. You can use `typeof` extension to make it a bit prettier: `typeof(int[2]) * array_of_smallest(int count) { .... }`

Comment: @JoaoLima See my appended answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue with returning the array is that it is not possible to declare Variably-Modified Type (like a pointer to VLA) at the file scope.

The reason of the problem can be explained as follow. Your code behaves more or less like this:

```
typedef int T[n];

T* array_of_smallest(int count) { ... }
```

Unfortunately, defining such a type `T` is not possible because of two reasons:

- `n` is usually not visible at file scope, except if it was a global variable
- evaluation of `n` would require code execution at file scope which is *forbidden*

### Workarounds

1. Return `void*` as described in other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72516342/4989451).
2. Pass a pointer to VLA in "by-reference" style, as a pointer to a pointer to array

```
void array_of_smallest(int count, int (**p)[n]) {
 ...
 *p = arr;
}
```

3. Return a pointer to incomplete array type of `int[]`. It is not possible to return incomplete types but it is possible to return a pointer to incomplete types:

```
int (*array_of_smallest(int count))[] { ... }
```

or a bit cleaner with a help of `typeof` extension (feature in C23)

```
typeof(int[]) *array_of_smallest(int count) { ... }
```

And use it as in the `void*` case:

```
int ( *arr )[n] = array_of_smallest( count );
```

This solution provides type-checking for the element type, however it works only for 2-dimensional arrays.

4. Wrap the pointer into a structure and use a macro to reconstruct its type on the client side:

```
typedef struct {
  int rows, cols;
  void* data;
} Arr2D;

Arr2D array_of_smallest(int count) {
  ...
  return (Arr2D) { .rows = i, .cols = n, .data = arr };
}

#define ARR2D_DEF_VIEW(view, arr2d) int (*view)[(arr2d).cols] = (arr2d).data

... usage ...

Arr2D arr = array_of_smallest(42);
ARR2D_DEF_VIEW(view, arr);

... do stuff with view[i][j]
}
```

Alternatively, use `typeof` extension to infer the type of VLA view rather than declare it in a macro:

```
#define ARR2D_VIEW_TYPE(arr2d) typeof(int(*)[(arr2d).cols])

...

Arr2D arr = array_of_smallest(42);
ARR2D_VIEW_TYPE(arr) view = arr.data;
```